# iPhone/iPad .ros configuration directory

Tags: ros, filesystem

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, after days of gruesome compiling and recompiling, I was able to build roscpp for the iPhone. I'll try to publish a detailed HowTo soon including finished frameworks for apr, apr-util, log4cxx, expat, boost and ros including armv6/7/i368 architectures.

I feel I'm stuck at a quite trivial problem now, but I don't know how to solve it. After trying to start my first node I get:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem3::filesystem_error'
what():  boost::filesystem::create_directory: Operation not permitted: "/private/var/mobile/Applications/XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/.ros/"

Which is logical since the iPhone's sandbox doesn't allow writing there. My question would be how to resolve this problem without messing with the roscpp code itself? Do I absolutely need the Configuration Dir? Is there some local/global parameter to influence its location?

Thanks for the help!
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10298/iphone/ipad-.ros-configuration-directory/) by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2011-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Set the environment variable ROS_HOME to something writable. It currently is .../.ros where you get the error.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2011-06-18**:
Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!